# how to check if a user input is stored in a sqlite database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

i am making a c# application that allows for user to register and login so far i have managed to get the registering portion done but i am stuck with the login portion

i have a method called ExecuteQuery which queries through the sqlite file that stores the user information and i am not sure how to check if the datastored in the database matches with the username and password the user enterd

this is the portion that is ment to check for the correct username and password this is the part i am stuck with

```
        if (File.Exists("Users.sqlite"))
        {

            string txtQuery = "select * from UserInfo where UserName ='"+ username + "' and Password  ='" + password + "'";
            mainClass.ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);

        }
```

this is my method that queries through the database

```
public void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
    {
        SetConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
        sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sql_con.Close();
    }
```

the problem is that i am not sure how to check if the user input and the user details stored in the sqlite database match. the name of my sqlite database is Users andthe name of the table is UserInfo

Comment: Assuming this is an academic exercise and nothing you would ever do in a production application, you could `select count(*) from...` and verify the result is an integer equal to 1 and use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Same comments as for the [same question from 1 hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54097434/1070452): *Dont glue data into strings to make queries - use SQL Parameters always. Then, do not store passwords as plain text - salt them and hash them. You should also learn about the using statement and what it means when something has a `Dispose` method*.  Also please dont spam the same post over and over

Answer (score -1):

You Execute Non Query, Execute non query not returning any data, it just executes the query, you use it in update, insert, delete, ETC ..

To Return results from your query, Use ExecuteQuery instead of ExecuteNonQuery. and save the results in a variable then return it.

Example:

```
public string ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
{
    SetConnection();
    sql_con.Open();
    var sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
    var x = sql_cmd.ExecuteQuery();
    sql_con.Close();
return x;
}
```

and in the main page:

```
 var result = mainClass.ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
```

Result will include your query, which in your case will be the user info if exists.

Please don't forget to mark it as an answer and vote. hope that I have helped you.

Comment: hai thanks for the response but when i try that the there is a red squiggly Line underneath the   var x = sql_cmd.ExecuteQuery(); portion and i cant run the application

Comment: `var sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();` make sure youre wrapping the sqlconnection and the sqlcommand in using statements as well...

Comment: @james poriam you are having trouble because there is no ExecuteQuery. Go to the docs and read about SqlCommand https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods